# Difference in redshift between 2 interacting galaxies

Tags: galaxy, cosmology, python, astropy

I have a galaxy 'A', say at redshift 1. Let's suppose this galaxy has no peculiar velocity. What would be the redshift of another galaxy 'B', that has a radial velocity of 500 km/s, relative to A?

All this in the standard (Planck) model.

Any tools to do get this easily (an python code, astropy?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From eq. 10 in [Hogg's classic paper](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/bib_query?arXiv:astro-ph/9905116), assuming that the peculiar velocity $v_\mathrm{pec} \ll c$:
$$v_\mathrm{pec} = c \frac{z_\mathrm{obs} - z_\mathrm{cos}}{1 + z_\mathrm{cos}},$$
where $z_\mathrm{obs}$ is the observed redshift, and $z_\mathrm{cos}$ is the redshift from cosmological expansion only.

Let me invert that and wrap it up in Python for ya:

```
def zobs(vpec,zcos):
  c = 3e5
  return (1+zcos) * vpec/c + zcos
```

Comment: Thanks for the ref and the very complete answer!
(and I corrected my typo thanks to you).

Comment: You very welcome @cbienpourtoi. I'll remove my first comment, then.